# Google Analytics (V2) Real-Time keeps reporting the user as in the main activity

Tags: android, google-analytics

My Application is formed of a Dashboard (GridView) with many Icons referring to Activities,

Whenever the user clicks on an Icon he's redirected to a new Activity but the main Activity is still open(only paused)

I'm Using Google Analytics V2.

Wherever the user goes through the App, The Real-Time in Google Analytics keeps reporting the user as if he's in the main Activity.

I tried to add the G.A. code to `onPause` and `onResume` but still it reports that the user is in the Main Activity.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(UserFunctions.getGASetting(getBaseContext())){
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(UserFunctions.getGASetting(getBaseContext())){
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(UserFunctions.getGASetting(getBaseContext())){
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onPause();
    if(UserFunctions.getGASetting(getBaseContext())){
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: In my case, I had set the "ga_dispatchPeriod" value to 0 in analytics.xml for instant dispatching according to documentaition in [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/dispatch). Today I changed this value to a positive integer like 1, and it's working now. I hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `ga_autoActivityTracking` to `true` in your analytics.xml file? See the docs for `EasyTracker.activityStart(Activity)` which says:

> Track the start of an Activity, but only if mIsAutoActivityTracking is true. This method will start a new session if necessary, and will send an empty event to Google Analytics if mIsAutoActivityTracking is false to ensure proper application-level tracking.

It sounds to me like it's sending an empty event because you have ga_autoActivityTracking ommited or set to false.